# How to keep GraphQL API and frontend synchronized on a staging server?

Tags: api, deployment, graphql, versioning, api-design

We have a Rails application with GraphQL API in one GIT repository, and React frontend application in another. Both backend and frontend have CI and are deployed separately. But both backend and frontend are still under heavy development and often our staging server doesn't work, because deployment is not synchronized and we don't test the whole application - we test API and we test frontend without API.

What is the best way to deploy frontend and backend only when they are synchronized, I mean when new versions doesn't break functionalities? I thought about third repository with backend and frontend included as GIT modules, acceptance tests and deploying both sides at once. But maybe there is simpler solution? Maybe some versioning?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly *can* do versioning with GraphQL, but ideally any changes to your schema shouldn't be breaking ones. This just takes discipline on the part of your backend devs, although there are also tools (like [this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-servicecheck)) to help detect breaking changes. Some general guidelines:

- Deprecate fields using the `@deprecated` directive instead of deleting them. Deprecated fields can be communicated to client teams and retired after some agreed-upon amount of time.
- Avoid renaming types. Try to use more specific naming to avoid having to rename things in the future (i.e. use `emailMessage` instead of just `message` if you could foreseeably have a different kind of message in the future).
- Use payload types for mutations. If you mutate a `User`, for example, instead of just returning the `User`, return a payload type that has a `user` field. If down the road, you realize the mutation should also return other information, you can easily add fields to the payload type without creating breaking changes.

Comment: What about situation, when someone on a backend adds a required field to the model, but it's still not implemented in a form on a frontend? We can't edit the model in this case. I would like to avoid such situations.

Comment: Yeah, adding a non-null *input* field or non-null argument would also be a breaking change. One solution is to deprecate the whole affected field and implement the changes under a differently named field.